Authentication between Frontend, Backend and Google OAuth2
I want to build an application that has a frontend for user interaction, a backend for logic handling, and I want to use OAuth2 for authentication.
I've done some reading and this seems to be the best solution for me right now.

However i still have some question:

This seems to be a good approach for Registering a new user. I'm thinking of modifying step 6 - storing the access token and refresh token in my backend database for later use. And step 7 - i will create my own JWT token for communicating between my frontend and backend after user has already authenticated with Google OAuth. For now i think this is a fine solution, is there anything worth noticing here?
After the first login, how should i handle when user login again? As far as i know, we now have the tokens stored in our backend (use the refresh token to get a new access token if it is expired) and should not ask the user to authenticate with google again every time they visit our page. But then how can we communicate between the frontend and the backend to use the stored tokens? I really can't think of a solution for this.

EDIT:
I've found this very useful link. However this still does not mention how to handle login using the tokens that we already have. Does this mean we have to login again every time the user visits our app? (I still think we do not have to)
